# Custom letter ordering with normal numeric ordering in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have a list of data tags as strings, much like this:

```
data <- c("ABCD 2", "ABCD 3", "WXYZ 1", "WXYZ 5", "WXYZ 3", "WXYZ 4", "ABCD 4", "ABCD 11")
```

Note that some numbers, including "1", are sometimes missing. A normal sort, of course, puts the `ABCD` tags before the `WXYZ` tags, and then puts `ABCD 11` before `ABCD 2`.

I can easily overcome the numbering issue with `gtools::mixedsort`. But, for reasons of problem-specific context, I *also* want the `WXYZ` tags to come before the `ABCD` ones.

For example, when `data` above is sorted as I need it, it should look like this:

```
dataSorted <- c("WXYZ 1", "WXYZ 3", "WXYZ 4", "WXYZ 5", "ABCD 2", "ABCD 3", "ABCD 4", "ABCD 11")
```

Thankfully, I only need to deal with those two types of tags now, but I figure I should ask for a general solution. Is there a way to make `gtools::mixedsort` do reverse alpha but normal numeric ordering? If I set `decreasing = TRUE` then it also reverses all the number orders.

Right now I am just using a list to force the order, and that is not only inelegant, but since the numbers on the tags have no theoretical upper limit, it is also going to eventually break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may extract the digits and non-digits separately, and then do the `order` after converting to `factor` with `levels` specified for the non-digits part

```
data[order(factor(sub("\\s+\\d+", "", data), 
   levels = c("WXYZ", "ABCD")), as.integer(sub("\\S+\\s+", "", data)))]
```

-output

```
[1] "WXYZ 1"  "WXYZ 3"  "WXYZ 4"  "WXYZ 5" 
[5] "ABCD 2"  "ABCD 3"  "ABCD 4"  "ABCD 11"
```

Comment: This looks perfect. I have a wait a little while to try and apply it (many cooks in the kitchen), but I will accept it if it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This works without any pre-definitions or manually entered data.
Only prerequisite is the first item has to be a letter-string and the second a number (introduces NA if number is missing).

First, split the strings by <kbd>space</kbd>, followed by a grouping by letters and a sort of the numbers within the group.
Then both have to be brought back together.

```
# split
dat <- setNames( data.frame( t(data.frame( strsplit( data, " " ) )[1,]),
  as.numeric( data.frame( strsplit( data, " " ) )[2,]) ), c("A","B") )
#                   A  B
#c..ABCD....2..  ABCD  2
#c..ABCD....3..  ABCD  3
#c..WXYZ....1..  WXYZ  1
#c..WXYZ....5..  WXYZ  5
#c..WXYZ....3..  WXYZ  3
#c..WXYZ....4..  WXYZ  4
#c..ABCD....4..  ABCD  4
#c..ABCD....11.. ABCD 11

# group and order
dat_agr <- aggregate( B ~ A, dat, na.action=na.pass, 
  function(x)sort(x, na.last=T), simplify=F )
dat_ord <- dat_agr[order(dat_agr[,"A"], decreasing=T),]
#     A           B
#2 WXYZ  1, 3, 4, 5
#1 ABCD 2, 3, 4, 11

# bring back together
unlist(lapply( dat_ord$A, function(x) sapply( 
  dat_ord[grep(x, dat_ord$A),"B"], function(y) paste(x,y) ) ))
[1] "WXYZ 1"  "WXYZ 3"  "WXYZ 4"  "WXYZ 5"  "ABCD 2"  "ABCD 3"  "ABCD 4" 
[8] "ABCD 11"
```