# R Sort or order with custom compare function

Tags: r, sorting, comparison

Can I pass a custom compare function to `order` that, given two items, indicates which one is ranked higher?

In my specific case I have the following list.

```
scores <- list(
    'a' = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4),
    'b' = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4),
    'c' = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4),
    'd' = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4)
)
```

If we take two vectors `a` and `b`, the index of the first element `i` at which `a[i] > b[i]` or `a[i] < b[i]` should determine what vector comes first. In this example, `scores[['d']] > scores[['a']]` because `scores[['d']][2] > scores[['a']][2]` (note that it doesn't matter that `scores[['d']][5] < scores[['a']][5]`).

Comparing two of those vectors could look something like this.

```
compare <- function(a, b) {
    # get first element index at which vectors differ
    i <- which.max(a != b)
    if(a[i] > b[i])
        1
    else if(a[i] < b[i])
        -1
    else
        0
}
```

The sorted keys of `scores` by using this comparison function should then be `d, b, a, c`.

From other solutions I've found, they [mess with the data before ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70038589/custom-letter-ordering-with-normal-numeric-ordering-in-r) or introduce [S3 classes and apply comparison attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676537/sorting-list-of-list-of-elements-of-a-custom-class-in-r). With the former I fail to see how to mess with my data (maybe turn it into strings? But then what about numbers above 9?), with the latter I feel uncomfortable introducing a new class into my R package only for comparing vectors. And there doesn't seem to be a sort of comparator parameter I'd want to pass to `order`.

Comment: @akrun I'm not quite sure what you mean by using combinatorics. What I'm aiming for is something frequently found in [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12749495/7669319), [cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16895019/7669319), [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24227670/7669319) or [Go](https://gobyexample.com/sorting-by-functions) where you're able to supply a compare function that simply compares two items.

Answer (score 4):

The native R way to do this is to introduce an S3 class.

There are two things you can do with the class.  You can define a method for `xtfrm` that converts your list entries to numbers.  That could be vectorized, and conceivably could be really fast.

But you were asking for a user defined compare function.  This is going to be slow because R function calls are slow, and it's a little clumsy because nobody does it.  But following the instructions in the `xtfrm` help page, here's how to do it:

```r
scores <- list(
  'a' = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4),
  'b' = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4),
  'c' = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4),
  'd' = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4)
)

# Add a class to the list

scores <- structure(scores, class = "lexico")

# Need to keep the class when subsetting

`[.lexico` <- function(x, i, ...) structure(unclass(x)[i], class = "lexico")

# Careful here:  identical() might be too strict

`==.lexico` <- function(a, b) {identical(a, b)}

`>.lexico` <- function(a, b) {
  a <- a[[1]]
  b <- b[[1]]
  i <- which(a != b)
  length(i) > 0 && a[i[1]] > b[i[1]]
}

is.na.lexico <- function(a) FALSE

sort(scores)
#> $c
#> [1] 1 1 2 2 3 4
#> 
#> $a
#> [1] 1 1 2 3 4 4
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 1 2 2 2 3 4
#> 
#> $d
#> [1] 1 2 3 3 3 4
#> 
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "lexico"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This is the opposite of the order you asked for, because by default `sort()` sorts to increasing order.  If you really want d, b, a, c use `sort(scores, decreasing = TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! Do you have any input on how that affects package development for CRAN, ie. should I be wary of simply adding new classes to lists, should I `#' @export` those `lexico` functions, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an attempt. I've explained every step in the comments.

```
compare <- function(a, b) {
  
  # subtract vector a from vector b
  comparison <- a - b
  # get the first non-zero result
  restult <- comparison[comparison != 0][1]
  # return 1 if result == 1 and 2 if result == -1 (0 if equal)
  if(is.na(restult)) {return(0)} else if(restult == 1) {return(1)} else {return(2)}
  
}

compare_list <- function(list_) {
  
  # get combinations of all possible comparison
  comparisons <- combn(length(list_), 2)
  # compare all possibilities
  results <- apply(comparisons, 2, function(x) {
    # get the "winner"
    x[compare(list_[[x[1]]], list_[[x[2]]])]
  })
  # get frequency table (how often a vector "won" -> this is the result you want)
  fr_tab <- table(results)
  # vector that is last in comparison
  last_vector <- which(!(1:length(list_) %in% as.numeric(names(fr_tab))))
  # return the sorted results and add the last vectors name
  c(as.numeric(names(sort(fr_tab, decreasing = T))), last_vector)
  
}
```

If you run the function on your example, the result is

```
> compare_list(scores)
[1] 4 2 1 3
```

I haven't dealt with the case that the two vectors are identical, you haven't explained how to deal with this.

Comment: I find it interesting to see `compn` used like this! Definitely learned something new there. My only worry is that the complexity seems to be somewhere in the `O(n^2)` area

Comment: That's true, though you could implement some form of a Monte Carlo Tree Search to eliminate some comparisons beforehand. E.g. compare `d` to only `b` then `c` to only `a` and then `b` to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another, very simple solution:

```
sort(sapply(scores, function(x) as.numeric(paste(x, collapse = ""))), decreasing = T)
```

What it does is, it takes all the the vectors, "compresses" them into a single numerical digit and then sorts those numbers in decreasing order.

Comment: Oh, I didn't consider the `as.numeric` part when thinking about condensing the vector. Neat! Do you have an idea on how to consider negative numbers as well? (eg. `c(-3, -1, 0, 4)` is greater than `c(-3, 0, 2, 5)`)

Comment: Since the vectors are monotone increasing, just add the smallest number to all vectors (in your example add 3 to all vectors). This ensures that all numbers in the vectors are positive.